# Call function on file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which I'm using to upload files. In current situation if a user choose an image from his computer he have to click button upload to upload the image. I'm trying to find a way to skip the step with a button pressing.

How to call a javascript function when the file is selected from user ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onchange` event is fired when a user specify a file for the upload filed. You could go about something like this:

```
<input type="file" name="someName" id="uploadID" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
var el = document.getElementById('#uploadID');
el.onchange = function(){
  // your code...
};
```

However, javascript validation is good idea but make sure that you do the actual validation on the **server-side** :)

Comment: Should be 'uploadID' instead of '#uploadID'.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example above...

```
<input type="file" name="someName" id="uploadID" />
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('uploadID').addEventListener('change', () => {
//Your code...
});
```